# Increase DIV width by float elements

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `div` with auto increase `width`.
I have tried this but it's not working:
What is the problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/silverlight/b6k8x/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="metro">
  <div class="rail">
    <div class="track">a</div>
    <div class="track">b</div>
    <div class="track">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.metro{
  position       :relative;
  background     :rgba(255, 255, 255, .03);
  width          :150px;
  height         :128px;
  padding-bottom :28px;
  overflow       :hidden;
  overflow-x     :scroll;
  }
.metro .rail{
    white-space:nowrap;
  position   :relative;
  width      :auto;
  background :rgba(255, 255, 205, .03);
  height     :128px;
  min-height :128px;
  overflow-y :hidden;
  }
.metro .rail .track{
  text-align:center;
  display    :inline-block;
  float        :left;
  margin-right :10px;
  width        :64px;
  height       :128px;
  background   :rgba(255, 105, 255, .3);
  }
```

Comment: please look at your question again. I do not understand what you want

Comment: Could you explain more what you are trying to achieve when you say "I want to make a div element that it's width wrapped by float contents in it"? It is currently unclear what you mean.

Comment: Sorry my english is bad, I mean where is "c" and why its not in right of "b" ?

Comment: Note that `float` makes `inline-block`s behave like (floated) `block`s. So either use `display: inline-block` or `float: left`, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't limit width of the metro class: http://jsfiddle.net/b6k8x/2/

```
.metro{
position       :relative;
background     :rgba(255, 255, 255, .03);
height         :128px;
padding-bottom :28px;
overflow       :hidden;
overflow-x     :scroll;
}
```

Comment: but i need to make width of `.metro` fixed, is there any chance to `.rail` `width` gets bigger?

Comment: remove float:left from .metro .rail .track . Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/b6k8x/6/

Answer (score 2):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6k8x/3/)

Remove

```
.metro{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.metro .rail .track{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the width of metro is too small, its only `150px`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b6k8x/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy.
Remove height and width of .metro

Answer (score 0):

You could use responsive layout to achieve what you are looking for. I have just tinkered a bit with your css. Your question wasn't very clear but I hope this is what you were looking for.

I have taken the liberty to assume that you want you parent element(.metro) to have a fixed width of 150px.

```
.metro{
  background     :rgba(255, 255, 255, .03);
  width          :150px;
  height         :128px;
  padding-bottom :28px;
  overflow       :hidden;
  overflow-x     :scroll;
  }
.metro .rail{
  white-space:nowrap;
  width      :auto;
  background :rgba(255, 255, 205, .03);
  height     :128px;
  min-height :128px;
  overflow-y :hidden;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 0;
  }
.metro .rail .track:last-child{
    margin: 0;
}
.metro .rail .track{
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:center;
  display    :inline-block;
  float        :left;
  margin-right :3%;
  height       :128px;
  background   :red;
  width: 30%;
  }
```

Comment: but i need to make `width` of `.metro` fixed, is there any chance to `.rail` `width` gets bigger?

Comment: When you use percentages the '.rail' will always be 100% of '.metro' which is be 150px, and you '.track' will fit into this parameters.